# Firebase Crashlytics and Sentry do not work together? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, sentry

I have to work with 2 different SDKs which should report the Crashs. Once is Firebase Crashlytics and the other is Sentry. The second one I need in the company for different tools. With Firebase I have a better overview in general.

My problem now is, I see only the crashs in Firebase, but not in Sentry. If I create by my own a crash, then it appears in both. I don't understand what is happen.

What I know is that when an app is crashing the OS creates the report and the SDK in the app is checking this with the next start of the app.

For me it looks like that Firebase catch the crash reports and Sentry didn't get it. But then why I can see my self created crashs in both?

Do you have some experience with both frameworks in one project?

Comment: Can you explain briefly what are the advantages of each? I understand that for crashes you have found Crashlytics to be better, right? Can you explain what are its advantages? And what are the pros of Sentry? Also, any idea who it is pricing-wise, crashlytics vs. sentry? Best if you can add this explanation to the question as an addition at the bottom (and mark it as not related to the question), since comments do not provide formatting, much more difficult to read..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This came up before, [including in the Sentry forum](https://forum.sentry.io/t/ios-use-sentry-and-fabric-at-the-same-time/590).

It's not a supported use case. Each error tracking SDK will attach to the signal handler to stack unwind during a crash and only one of them will succeed.

EDIT: We did some tests and it seems to work. At least on the device we tested, connected to WiFi, etc. That said, we heard reports that it didn't work in other cases.
So as I wrote on the comment below, it's undefined behavior and not recommended to be relied upon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bruno. What does this means - both are checking the crash information but only one can handle it? At the link I see there is no problem with both. For me I can see that is different.

Comment: It's just undefined behavior, it's likely not possible to stack unwind twice. The code that you're allowed to run in the signal handler is limited